# How to add chatting application to django website

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, chat

I want a very basic simplest way for users on website to chat. How can I do it? can I integrate any chat platform with it, like hangouts or etc. I was thinking I can use emails in any way but that would so brute. suggest easy to implement and basic methods because it is a large website and chatting is not its core part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have neither personally implemented a solution for a problem like this nor looked for solutions or libraries. However, I recommend you to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv5jlmJs2sU&list=PLLRM7ROnmA9EnQmnfTgUzCfzbbnc-oEbZ) video series, from the YouTube channel "JustDjango". I have personally watched many of its tutorials and I found them really helpful and enjoyable. So, if there is any advice that I could give you that is. Also, you can search for Node.js because it supports socket.io and it offers much more than Django Channels.

I hope that helps you a little bit, good luck with your project!

Comment: if you could tell @georgekrax , to use pdf.js or any library of javascript do I have to integrate node.js with django website

Comment: Yes, all JavaScript libraries should be used with Node.js or within a HTML <script> tag. I guess you could find similar libraries or packages for Python. Do not attempt the opposite, you will find libraries solving your issues for Python & JavaScript because they are on the trend and the are supported a lot by the open-source community.